# What's the difference between MemoryCache.Add and MemoryCache.Set?

Tags: .net, memorycache

I read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780623(v=vs.110).aspx) but didn't really understand it.

I believe that the behavior of `Set` is "replace existing, or add" (atomically).

Is that correct?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

`Add` does nothing (returns `false`) if there is already a value for that key. `Set` does an insert or update, as necessary.

`Remove` + `Add` would leave a gap in the middle when another thread querying that key would get no clue (`Set` does not; the swap is typically atomic); as such, while `Set` has the same **end result** as `Remove` + `Add`, the mechanism difference is important since it could impact other callers.

For example of [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780614.aspx):

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Boolean true if insertion succeeded, or false if there is an already an entry in the cache that has the same key as key.

Comment: Does `set` replaces Policy if item exists?

Comment: I just saw your almost year old message, I am working on similar issue.  All SET overloads require a Policy, so the answer is yes.

Comment: if I use Add function on an expired cache? will it be replaced with the updated CacheItem?